# How to make vim use buffer instead of stdout by default?

Tags: vim

I searched all over the internet, but didn't find an answer.

I found plugin "AsyncCommand", but I don't want to type :AsyncCommand everytime. I just want vim to pipe stdout to a buffer by default.

Is it even possible? Do you know any plugin that can do this?

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin named [Vim Pipe](https://github.com/krisajenkins/vim-pipe) that does exactly this.  Very useful within its scope.

Comment: As far as I understood from readme this plugin allows to define commands and then execute them against current buffer. Can it pipe all stdout to vim buffer by default?

Comment: @GeraldAgapov No, that isn't possible.  The plugin I mentioned is pretty much as far as you can go with Vim.